# Is there a disk space analyzer that lets you save the disk image?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, space

I've seen there are a number of different applications for OSX that lets you visualize disk space and browse the category tree as an index - JDiskReport, DaisyDisk, Disk Inventory X, etc.
I would like to be able to save the disk image and directory tree that these applications generate for future reference and browsing. Does anyone know if any application of this kind allow for that?
I can't find this information in these applications' online feature spec.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some more research and found out that at least JDiskReport has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply take a picture of a portion of the window that contains what you want with `command + shift + 4`, and use the cursor to select, or use `command + shift + 4` then `space bar` and select the entire window.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was a bit unprecise in my question. I use the term "disk image" as refering to the entire browsable index. I'm not particularly intereseted in the graphical image. Thanks for helping, though.